# LiteServAndroid could not able to configuring project

Tags: couchdb, replication, android-studio, touchdb

Liteservandroid is an application that is used as Http api/Restful api to connect to CouchDB from TouchDB. I got a sample project and when i tried to build the project, i got the following error.

```
Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':LiteServAndroid'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

There were no pointing errors in the code section. Can any one help me to find a solution.

Thanks

Chinna

Answer (score 0):

The first hint I see with your problem is that in August 2013  you are talking about TouchDB - and TouchDB name change was introduced as far back as January 2013.  There are old projects sitting out there using out of date code.

Are you sure you are using the newer code base? Here is the direct link to the ListServAndroid project https://github.com/couchbaselabs/LiteServAndroid

I found Couchbase Lite to be a bit tricky to integrate.  They have moved it all over to Android Studio for building and developing too... so that might be new learning also. Have you gotten the GrocerySync test application working?